# How to narrow the Option type inferred from fp-ts R.lookup

Tags: javascript, fp-ts

I am trying to lookup the value of a key with `fp-ts`. The key might not be present.

```
type Data = {
  a?: number;
  b?: string;
  c?: { e?: string; w: number };
};

const e = R.lookup('b')({ a: 23, b: 'asdfasdf', c: { e: 'asdf', w: 23}} as Data)
```

I thought the type of `e` inferred by Typescript would be `Option<string>` but it is:

```
O.Option<string | number | {
    e?: string | undefined;
    w: number;
}>
```

This looks like all the possible types in `Data`. Is this intended behaviour? And how shall I narrow my types to only the "potential" type of `b`, so that I can continue a pipeline from an `Option<string>`.

I tried the approach below, which marks `e` as `Option<string>` but then flags the entire object `{a: 23...` as "not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>'"

```
const getB = R.lookup("b")
const e = getB<string>({ a: 234, b: "asdfasdf", c: { e: "asdf", w: 23 } } as Data);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/// Argument of type 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>'.
  Property 'a' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `R.lookup`'s types just misalign with what you're hoping for. The problem is that `R.lookup` does not keep track of the fact that you're expecting `'b'` to be a `keyof Data`. It just knows that `b` is a `string` and the function it returns has the signature:

```
<A>(record: Record<string, A>) => Option<A>
```

So it looks at data as a `Record` and the type for A becomes `Data[keyof Data]` which results in the type you're seeing.

I think this mainly just stems from wanting to use a `Record` in a way it's not really intended to be used. A `Record` has a uniform type for any key you hand into it. In order to get a uniform type, the `fp-ts` code has to infer that at each key there might be the union type of all the values in data.

If instead, you know that you have a `Data` object, you can write code like:

```
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';
const data: Data = { a: 234, b: "asdfasdf", c: { e: "asdf", w: 23 } };
const maybeB: Option<string> = O.fromNullable(data.b);
```

If instead, you don't actually know that you'll have `Data` because your object is actually `unknown`, rather than casting it to `Data` you could use a library (like [`io-ts`](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) since you're already using `fp-ts`) to first validate the shape of the data. For example

```
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';
import { flow } from 'fp-ts/function';

import * as t from 'io-ts';

const dataSchema = t.partial({
  a: t.number,
  b: t.string,
  c: t.type({
    e: t.union([t.string, t.undefined]),
    w: t.number,
  }),
});

// This will be equivalent to your data definition but can be inferred
// from the schema definition
type Data = t.TypeOf<typeof dataSchema>;

// The explicit type here is unnecessary but just to illustrate
const getB: (input: unknown) => O.Option<string> = flow(
  dataSchema.decode, // -> Either<t.Errors, Data>
  O.fromEither, // -> Option<Data>
  O.chain((d) => O.fromNullable(d.b)) // Option<string>
);

console.log(getB(data)); // { _tag: 'Some', value: 'asdfasdf' }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, it makes a lot of sense! 

I am just a bit surprised that there is no function to do the first approach (i.e “I know I have Data”) in a point free way when in a pipe.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned this in my answer as well, but there's also the [`monocle-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts) library from the same people that do `io-ts` and `fp-ts` which sounds like what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per other comments, possibly the ideal approach to this would be using `io-ts` for `monocle-ts`. But seeing you seem interested in how `fp-ts` could handle it itself - for just a single field - I offer you this.

The gist is, that once you have got yourself the optional, you simply need to use typescript type narrowing. This can be done with `fp-ts` various `fromPredicate` with the overloaded form using a `Refinement`. And for a lot of basic types (like `string`) `fp-ts` provide some out of the box - such as `S.isString` below.

```js
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/function";
import * as O from "fp-ts/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/Record";
import * as S from "fp-ts/string";

type Data = {
  a?: number;
  b?: string;
  c?: { e?: string; w: number };
};

const testData: Data = { a: 23, b: "asdfasdf", c: { e: "asdf", w: 23 } };

const b = pipe(
  testData,
  R.lookup("b"),
  O.chain(
    O.fromPredicate(S.isString)
  )
);
```

But although that gets you by with the single field, anything more that that is going to require more and more boilerplate, so then you might as well use `io-ts`.